# Get the username password and role values from the JSP and set in bean Spring

Tags: java, spring, jsp, jakarta-ee

I've a JSP with a drop-down and 2 text fields for user  to select the role  and to enter username and password respectively. I need to get the user selected role and the `uname` and `pwd` and set it in the bean. Please help me !! am very new to Spring.. tell me from the basic like how I should pass that.

How to get the username password and role values from the JSP and set in the bean using Java spring?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function enableTextBox() {
                if (document.getElementById("dropdown").value == "Admin") {
                    document.getElementById("uname").disabled = false;
                    document.getElementById("pwd").disabled = false;
                } else {
                    document.getElementById("uname").disabled = true;
                    document.getElementById("pwd").disabled = true;
                }
            }

            function doClear() {
                document.getElementById("uname").value = "";
                document.getElementById("pwd").value = "";
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <table border=0 width=100% height=100%>
            <tr>
                <td valign="middle" align="center">
                    <table border="1" bordercolorlight="#C0C0C0" style="border-collapse: collapse"
                    bordercolor="#C0C0C0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                        <tr>
                            <td valign="middle" align="center" style="width: 400px">
                                <table border="0">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td colspan=2>
                                            <p align="center">
                                                <img src="images/logo.jpg" width="144" height="66">
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <td align="center" colspan=2>
                                        <FONT COLOR=BLUE SIZE=3>Welcome</FONT>
                                    </td>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td align="center" colspan=2>
                                            <STRONG><font size="4">Auction Site </font> </STRONG><font size="4"><BR>
     </font>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <tr align=center>
                                            <td align="right"><b>Select your role:</b>
                                            </td>
                                            <td align="left">
                                                <select name="dropdown" id="dropdown" onchange="enableTextBox();">
                                                    <option value="Admin">Admin</option>
                                                    <option value="csc">CSC Employee</option>
                                                </select>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr align=center>
                                            <td align="right"><b>User ID:</b>
                                            </td>
                                            <td align="left">
                                                <input type="text" id="uname" name="uname" value="" size="15" />
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr align=center>
                                            <td align="right"><b>Password:</b>
                                            </td>
                                            <td align="left">
                                                <input type=password id="pwd" name="pwd" value="" size="15" />
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr align=center>
                                            <input type="submit" id="sub" name="sub" value="Submit" size="15" />
                                            <td align="left">
                                                <input type="button" id="clr" name="clr" value="Reset" onclick="doClear()"
                                                />
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                            </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
                </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please share the code for JSP first.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) I mean *besides* asking random strangers on the internet to do it for you.

Comment: @Amber Shared the JSP code!! Thanks

Comment: @AndrewThompson To be frank i dint know how to proceed with  please help me..!!

Comment: JSP forms the view part in Spring Applications. Please first refer to some tutorials on that. JSP will get converted to HTML page and there username and passwords will be in a Form which when submitted will fill a form in controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont mention anything about where the username/role comes from or is stored.
So I assume you are approaching this in a the wrong for a spring MVC app.
Perhaps you have come from php or something, where you just put your code in the php file and display the value in html, also in the same file.

In MVC, there is a completely different way of approaching things.
First you should consider your model/domain.  This would be a User object and a Role object in your case.
Then you would build controllers to manage these objects.  Then you would look at views (jsp) to present these objects to the end user.  So in your case, jsp is the last thing to consider.

I recommend using spring ROO to build your simple app.  It will generate/scaffold a spring MVC app based on your model/domain classes.  It also uses all the spring best practices, so is a good way to learn how it all works.